# How can I bypass Kahoot's 2FA feature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I've been using the [Kahoot.js-updated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kahoot.js-updated) npm package with use Kahoot's API. Everything works fine, but I've noticed that Kahoot added a 2-Factor-Authentication (2FA) feature that adds an extra step to joining a quiz, apart from just punching in the quiz PIN. So I did some research and found out the Kahoot's 2FA feature has a vulnerability in the code. So I analysed the source code to the 2FA feature, but I could not completely understand the code and/or find a vulnerability. So my question is plain and simple: how do I bypass the Kahoot's new 2FA feature? Ideally I would hope for solution to be some code. But I'm open to any option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT bypass security features. Apart from the moral aspect -- any security bugs one exploits are likely going to be patched eventually. If you think new features are counterproductive, message the Kahoot team about it and they may be willing to fix things.

That said, the package doesn't seem to be requiring 2 factor authentication. Both the basic usage example (https://github.com/theusaf/kahoot.js-updated/blob/master/examples/basicUsage.js), as well as the advanced usage example (https://github.com/theusaf/kahoot.js-updated/blob/master/examples/advancedUsage.js), use the same line of code to join a quiz: `k.join(7877502 /* Or any other kahoot token */, "kahoot.js")`. These examples are still working, apart from the invalid room token.

According to docs, there are really only two functions that have anything to do with 2 step verification, neither of which are documented super well and aren't present in any examples. Cut from the documentation:

```
answer2Step(steps)
Parameters:
steps (array) - An array of the steps for the 2 step authentification. (numbers 0-3)
Returns: Promise
```

```
on('2Step') - Emitted when the 2 step authentification is sent to the client / refeshed
```

So, to answer your question, use this: `k.join(7877502 /* Or any other kahoot token */, "kahoot.js")`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the time. Sorry for my stupid intent of bypassing 2FA. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So it worked but I had to brute force every possibility (24) which was inefficient. Because the 2FA combo changes every 7 seconds. So is there a easier way to answer 2FA? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you brute-forcing? Can you post some code so we can see how you're engaging the api? Also, 2FA is not required for a connection with a quiz -- its likely intended for users trying play while logged into their accounts. Is this what you're trying to build?